Spring boot application-custom.properties
I have a spring boot application which is working fine when server field values are put in application.properties and read. But, my application can have dynamic server values. So, while running java -jar your-app.jar server nam application will take all properties for nam server, java -jar your-app.jar server euro will take all properties for euro server. How can I achieve this.
I was thinking of two files application.nam.properties and application.euro.properties and pass that java -jar your-app.jar --spring-config-location=file:///application.euro.properties

You can use active profiles to accomplish this.  In your example you would have an application-nam.properties and an application-euro.properties.  The euro properties would be activated using --spring.profiles.active=euro.  You could set any common properties directly in application.properties.
Documentation can be found here

As Josh mentioned above you have to create application-euro.properties file in application resources folder.
There are 2 ways to get this functionality when you want to pass config through command.
1. With VM arguments in command like this
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=euro your-app.jar
-D is important in the above command. Spring Boot makes -D arguments available as properties accessible from a Spring Environment instance.(Spring Doc)
2. Program Arguments
And if you want to get this with config. Use this command
java -jar your-app.jar --spring.profiles.active=euro --spring.config.location=c:\config
